# Rename CocoaPods project files missing?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I want to change my iOS application's name from "XXX_YYY" to just "XXXYYY". Inside Xcode I change the app's name on the left hand navigator:

[image: nav]

I then go into my Podfile and change the line `target 'XXX_YYY' do` to `target 'XXXYYY' do`, then run `pod install`.

Back in Xcode I run my simulator and my app seems to run fine but I'm getting many missing file errors, such as this one:

```
file:///Users/me/XcodeProj/XXX_YYY/Pods/Target%20Support%20Files/Pods-XXX_YYY/Pods-XXX_YYY.modulemap: warning: Missing file: /Users/me/XcodeProj/XXX_YYY/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXX_YYY/Pods-XXX_YYY.modulemap is missing from working copy
```

Did I incorrectly change the application's name or did I just forget to do  a step? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you went through the process correctly. You'll probably just need to clean the build directory (Cmd+Shift+K or Cmd+Option+Shift+K).

The other common issue is that you may not have saved your Podfile in Sublime or whatever text editor you're using. If you're used to XCode autosaving the source files it's easy to forget.

You can also change the target name in Manage Schemes. From tdubik:
"Press on the target name in xcode ( in the same place where you want to select the sim/device type) and select "Manage Schemes...". Highlight the scheme with the copy inside name and press enter on keyboard. You can rename it there."

Answer (score 0):

Delete the PODS directory created in Project directory and do a fresh pod install, then do a clean build. This will fix the issue.